# Google Map autocomplete into ajax injection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using a Ajax method to open a partial for my new event. Into this partial, I have a form to create an event.

So I would like to use the gmaps autocomplete into this injected partial.

I already use this code into a static form (no ajax to render it). And it's working great (so the api is well set). But when I try to re use this code into a partial injected through AJAX, it's not working anymore !

The partial injected for the new event :

```
# events/_new.html.erb

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAnjmxMT31wiBEdoIn3vgjpnynAGjxY1Ds"></script>

<div class="modal" id="new_event">
  <div class="col s12">
    <label for="autocomplete-input">Adresse</label>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete_address" name="adress" class="autocomplete">
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="company_info_adress" name="company_info_adress" style="display: none;">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new_event').modal();
    $('#new_event').modal("open");

    function initializeAutocomplete(id) {  
      var element = document.getElementById(id);  
      if (element) {    
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, { types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'FR'
          } });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
      }
    }
    function onPlaceChanged() {  
      var place = this.getPlace();
      $('#company_info_adress').val(place.formatted_address);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
      initializeAutocomplete('autocomplete_address');
    });
  });

</script>
```

I guess it's the line : `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {` which should be updated to correspond to my ajax render

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558724/using-adddomlistener-with-googlemaps-not-working